# Email Not Being Sent in Laravel 8 using Mailgun API

Tags: php, mailgun, laravel-8

I set up my mailgun account and was trying to use the sandbox domain to test sending email using API and not smtp. This is how my Laravel `.env` file was set up

```
MAIL_MAILER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandboxxxxxxx.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxxxxxx
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net/v3/<mailgun-domain>
```

Then I was using this in my controller to send the email.

```
    $emailToSendTo = Page::where('name', 'contact')->first()->email;

    Mail::to($emailToSendTo)->send(new ContactSent($request));
```

My email is not being sent as I look into the mailgun dashboard. I am also not getting any error message. Also I know that mailgun restricts the emails you can send to in the sandbox domain to what you set up in mailgun. The `$emailToSendTo` is a verified email.

The `ContactSent` class has been set up fine with the blade view.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question so it helps someone.

I put this inside `vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php` and the method `send()`:

```
dd($this->endpoint);
```

Then I tried to call the method which sends mail. I noticed that the `MAILGUN_ENDPOINT` was not set up properly therefore `dd($this->endpoint)` showed me the wrong endpoint.

It should be:

```
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.mailgun.net
```

This solved my issue. I hope this will help someone debug. Also I really think that the environment variable should be named `MAILGUN_BASE_URL` as it confused the crap out of me.

Comment: The usage of MAILGUN_ENDPOINT is optional, only to be used if you need to specify the EU region. It's quite clear in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#mailgun-driver

Also the "ENDPOINT" naming comes from mailgun not related to what laravel designed: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#errors

Comment: ha didn't notice that thanks @EstebanGarcia but it didn't throw any error. Maybe needs a pull request.